# table headers and scrollable table not rendering perfectly

Tags: jquery, css

I have 2 different tables, one for the header data and a second for a scrollable body.

```
<div class="form-horizontal" style="margin-top:15px;">
    <table id="header">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th></th>
                ...8x
            </tr>
        </thead>
    </table>
    <div id="table-container" style="overflow-y:auto; max-height:150px;">
    <table class="table" id="table">
        <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td ></td>
                    ...8x
                </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

Now I want to set the width of the tables with JQuery.

```
$('#table td:nth-child(1)').width('8%');
$('#table td:nth-child(2)').width('8%');
$('#table td:nth-child(3)').width('8%');
$('#table td:nth-child(4)').width('0%');
$('#table td:nth-child(5)').width('8%');
$('#table td:nth-child(6)').width('8%');
$('#table td:nth-child(7)').width('23%');
$('#table td:nth-child(8)').width('23%');
$('#header th:nth-child(1)').width('8%');
$('#header th:nth-child(2)').width('8%');
$('#header th:nth-child(3)').width('8%');
$('#header th:nth-child(4)').width('0%');
$('#header th:nth-child(5)').width('8%');
$('#header th:nth-child(6)').width('8%');
$('#header th:nth-child(7)').width('23%');
$('#header th:nth-child(8)').width('23%');
```

When startup the project the header is rendered as (example first column):

```
<th style="width: 10%;"></th>
```

(expected width: 8%)

and the body is renderd as (example first column):

```
<td style="width: 16%;"></td>
```

(expected width: 8%)

so the lay-out doesn't match. Why is the rendered output different than the expected?

(**off the question**, I fixed the probelem by setting the td the same width as the th with JQuery:

```
var ths = $('#header').children('thead').children('tr').children('th').length;
    for (counter = ths; counter >= 0; counter--) {
        var headerwidht = $('#header th:nth-child(' + counter + ')').width();
        $('#table td:nth-child(' + counter + ')').width(headerwidht + 'px');
    }
```

but I'm still curious why the table renders unexpectedly.
)

Comment: Why are you using jQuery for this instead of CSS?

Comment: Becaus of the 4th column, this can be hidden or not. So with JQuery I resize the table. And I did it in the first place with CSS but when the column was hidden the layout was more different.

Comment: Works fine for me http://jsfiddle.net/m42k8pf7/1, have you got other scripts running on it?

Comment: I have tested your code using jQuery 2.1.4 (https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js) and firefox 38.0.5 on Windows 7. The results were as expected in this setup. I can't see the error.

Comment: Strange, the headers are always 2% wider here. The other runing scripts are kendo, bootstrap and Jquery(1.10 and UI 1.11) and ofcourse my script but this is the only place where I'm manipulating the width

Comment: try changing selector's names

Comment: @maioman good luck with giving that a scrollable body

Comment: nop, changing the selector name didn't solve the problem. Same result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After hours of searching I fixed the problem by using the `.css('width' '*%')` instead of the `.width('*%')` 
This solved the problem.

Looking at the code the first column:

```
$('#header th:nth-child(1)').css('width', '6%');
```

now returns:

```
<th style="width: 6%;"></th>
```

I don't know why this solves the problem, but it fix it

Answer (score 0):

Do you have css "table-layout: fixed" for both of your tables?
You should have it when you set width for td/th of a table with percentage.

BTW, since the sum of total width percentages not need equal to 100%, you should use JS to toggle a class for your tables, without change their widths. And base the class, you can use CSS to show/hide columns with you want, or even change remain columns' width if needed.

Hope this can help.